# Python sorted() with itemgetter and comparer

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting

I have a comparer function that is being wrapped with `functools.cmp_to_key` so that I can use it when calling `sorted()`.

The problem is that I am already using `itemgetter` as the key. The itemgetter is being used to retrieve a value from a dictionary, and this value is what is being used to sort the collection.

So, essentially, I need to be using the itemgetter to retrieve the values, and then I need to use the comparer function to properly sort them.

I have tried the following combinations, but none seem to work:

```
for x in range( 0, len(sort_columns) ):
  comparer = cmp_to_key(sort_columns[x].sort_func)
  results = sorted( data, key=comparer )
  results = sorted( data, key=comparer(itemgetter( sort_columns[x] ) ) )
  results = sorted( data, key=itemgetter( comparer( sort_columns[x] ) ) )
```

In cases where a specific comparer isn't needed, it is just called as:

```
results = sorted( data, key=itemgetter( sort_columns[x] ) )
```

Comment: Is `sort_solumns` a typo? Or did you mean : `for item, columns in zip(sort_solumns, sort_columns): ...`?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga yes, that was a typo. Thank you for pointing that out. The original post has been updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to *compose* the getter and the comparer. Something to the effect of:

```
for columns in sort_columns: # don't use a range loop unless you need to
    comparer = cmp_to_key(columns.sort_func)
    getter = itemgetter(columns)
    data = sorted(data, key=lambda x: comparer(getter(x)))
```